# MDF File C# Build Replace Actual Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using a SQL Server `.MDF` database file in my C# Winforms application. I am also using EF6 to manage the database.

The problem is that every time I build, a new database is copied into the `bin` directory thus replacing any data that I have already inserted.

This makes me have 2 databases.

Is it possible to perform any changes to the original database I have created and the application refers to that database rather than creating a new one?

I know there are the copy to output directory options:

1. Do not copy (Gives an error because now the db is not found during runtime)
2. Copy if newer (This creates a problem because if i have already data into the database and i perform a change from the database model from VS it will copy the new file ok with the new modifications but will obviously remove all the data there is in the database)
3. Copy always (Will replace the db with an empty one every time)

How can I have only 1 unique database?

Comment: Since SQL Server really - already in its name - is a **server-based** product, my recommendation is to put the database **on the server** where it belongs and stop fiddling around with free-floating `.mdf` files. Create the database on the server, using SQL scripts or EF migrations, and connect to it from your clients - but don't copy around `.mdf` files and stuff like that ....

Comment: What you describe is perfectly normal. The database in your project is just content that's copied to the output folder along with all other content files. SQL Server is a *server-base* database. It doesn't work with files. It does offer user-instance databases, where the SQL Server *Express* engine attaches to a file only when an application starts.

Comment: `How can I have only 1 unique database?` don't use a user-instance database

Comment: There is no need to include the database in your c# project.  Remove it from the project so it doesn't get copied.  Your connection string should specify where the mdf file is located.

Comment: This is a small application i do not need alot of data in it and it is going to be an application that runs locally on a specific pc. I tried to refer to the original db in the connection string of app.config by writing ..\..\database.mdf but it does not open as it is not found for some reason

Comment: You shouldn't need a path - use a named connection string. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5d065a/tutorial-1sql-server-database-connection-in-window-form/